# ¿Como hacer una consulta mysql para reporte contable?

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos necesito su ayuda en una consulta para un reporte contable, exactamente para el Balance General y Balance de perdidas y ganancias.

Lo que necesito es hacer un reporte de sumas totales por cuenta principal, subcuenta1(cc_sc1) hasta la subcuenta5 (cc_sc5)

La consulta lleva un JOIN a otra tabla de asientos_contables donde están los valores y se unen por el código, he intentado hacer la consulta pero no se como hacerla.

```
select  IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),0) as totdebe,  IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),0) as tothaber, cc.cc_codigo,cc.cc_nombre, cc.cc_tipo, cc.cc_cp,cc.cc_visible from cuentascontables as cc LEFT JOIN asientos_contables as ac ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo group by cc.cc_codigo order by cc.cc_id ASC
```

Acá están las imágenes de mis tablas
[image: Tabla cuentascontables][image: Tabla asientos_contables]

Espero su ayuda.

ACTUALIZACION

Esta es la estructura de las tablas
Cuentascontables.

```
CREATE TABLE `cuentascontables` (
`cc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`cc_nombre` text NOT NULL,
`cc_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1. Principal , 2 subcuenta',
`cc_codigo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`cc_cp` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc2` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc3` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc4` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc5` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc6` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_sc7` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`cc_visible` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1 visiable, 2 no visible',
`cc_fechar` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Asientos_contables

```
CREATE TABLE `asientos_contables` (
`ac_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ac_fecha` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fecha de 
 creacion del asiento',
`ac_mes` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ac_anio` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ac_detalle` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`cc_codigo` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ac_debe` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`ac_haber` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`oc_tipotrans` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
 `ac_key` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `cac_key` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ac_reg` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`banc_key` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Hice unas pruebas pero no logro tener el resultado que deseo.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rt.totdebe),
     0) AS rttotdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(rt.tothaber),
     0) AS rttothaber,
     rt.cc_id AS rtcuentaID,
     rt.cc_codigo,
     rt.cc_nombre,
     rt.cc_tipo,
     rt.cc_cp,
     rt.cc_visible,
     rt.cc_id  FROM( 
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
FROM cuentascontables AS cc
LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
    ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
GROUP BY  cc.cc_cp
ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
UNION
ALL 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
    FROM cuentascontables AS cc
    LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
        ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
    GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc1
    ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
    UNION
    ALL 
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
        FROM cuentascontables AS cc
        LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
            ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
        GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc2
        ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
        UNION
        ALL 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
            FROM cuentascontables AS cc
            LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
                ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
            GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc3
            ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
            UNION
            ALL 
                (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
                FROM cuentascontables AS cc
                LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
                    ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
                GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc4
                ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC) ) AS rt
            GROUP BY  rt.cc_codigo
        ORDER BY  rt.cc_id ASC
```

Pero el resultado no es el deseado
[image: Resultado mi consulta]
Como ven en la imagen me sale los campos duplicados

Comment: Podrías subir la definición de las tablas? Para hacer el `JOIN` es necesario saber como "enlazar" las tablas, es decir cuales son las claves foráneas (FK) de tu tabla y cómo esa columna se llama en la tabla *asientos_contables* (es decir cual sería su clave primaria PK)

Comment: Claro, ya subo la estructura de las tablas

Answer (score 0):

Hola hice unas pruebas pero no logro tener el resultado que deseo.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rt.totdebe),
     0) AS rttotdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(rt.tothaber),
     0) AS rttothaber,
     rt.cc_id AS rtcuentaID,
     rt.cc_codigo,
     rt.cc_nombre,
     rt.cc_tipo,
     rt.cc_cp,
     rt.cc_visible,
     rt.cc_id  FROM( 
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
FROM cuentascontables AS cc
LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
    ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
GROUP BY  cc.cc_cp
ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
UNION
ALL 
    (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
    FROM cuentascontables AS cc
    LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
        ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
    GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc1
    ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
    UNION
    ALL 
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
        FROM cuentascontables AS cc
        LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
            ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
        GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc2
        ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
        UNION
        ALL 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
            FROM cuentascontables AS cc
            LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
                ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
            GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc3
            ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC )
            UNION
            ALL 
                (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ac_debe),
     0) AS totdebe,
     IFNULL(SUM(ac_haber),
     0) AS tothaber,
     cc.cc_id AS cuentaID,
     cc.cc_codigo,
     cc.cc_nombre,
     cc.cc_tipo,
     cc.cc_cp,
     cc.cc_visible,
     cc.cc_id
                FROM cuentascontables AS cc
                LEFT JOIN asientos_contables AS ac
                    ON cc.cc_codigo=ac.cc_codigo
                GROUP BY  cc.cc_sc4
                ORDER BY  cc.cc_id ASC) ) AS rt
            GROUP BY  rt.cc_codigo
        ORDER BY  rt.cc_id ASC
```

Pero el resultado no es el deseado
[image: Resultado mi consulta]
Como ven en la imagen me sale los campos duplicados

Comment: Esto debería ir como edición a tu pregunta entonces amigo y no como respuesta